# subprocess32.check_output does not raise TimeoutExpired if the process isn't killed

Tags: python, subprocess, timeout

When using subprocess32's method `check_output`, there are occasions in which `TimeoutExpired` is not raised even though the time has passed and the process did not complete.

Looking at the source code of `subprocess32`, I stumbled upon the following piece of code:

```
 try:
    output, unused_err = process.communicate(timeout=timeout)
except TimeoutExpired:
    process.kill()
    output, unused_err = process.communicate()
    raise TimeoutExpired(process.args, timeout, output=output)
```

It seems that if the process will not respond to SIGKILL issues by `process.kill()`, 
the interpreter might hang on `process.communicate()` indefinitely, thus not raising the `TimeoutExpired` exception, as I expected.

What am I missing here? Is there a better practice of invoking a process whilst making sure a timeout would be thrown if necessary, consistently?

Thanks!